# How to set timeout for session?

Tags: php, session

Is there any way to set time limitation for session? It means that my application should log out after 1 hour through server settings not like coding level as below.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 7200)) {
    // last request was more than 120 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}

$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, store the last time the user made a request

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
?>
```

in subsequent request, check how long ago they made their previous request (30 minutes in this example)

```
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']){

  if ($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] + 30 * 60 < time()) {

     // session timed out
     session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
     session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
  } else {

    // session ok
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$timeout = 60*60;//1 hour
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionTime'])) {
        $_SESSION['sessionTime'] = time() + $timeout;//first login, set timeout
    } else {
        if ($_SESSION['sessionTime'] < time()) {//over timeout, destroy session
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
        } else {
            $_SESSION['sessionTime'] = time() + $timeout;//login in timeout, reset timeout
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
// last request was more than 30 minutes ago
session_unset(); // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
session_destroy(); // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp

/*
You can also use an additional time stamp to regenerate the session ID periodically to avoid attacks on sessions like session fixation:
*/

if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
$_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 1800) {
// session started more than 30 minutes ago
session_regenerate_id(true); // change session ID for the current session an invalidate old session ID
$_SESSION['CREATED'] = time(); // update creation time
}

//note that session.gc_maxlifetime should be at least equal to the life time of this custom expiration handler (1800 in this example).
```

[description here](http://snipplr.com/view/72803/how-to-expire-a-php-session-after-x-minutes/)

Answer (score 1):

**Cause the question was "not on coding level"** => You could achieve this via php.ini and/or .htaccess by setting session.gc_maxlifetime and/or session.cookie_lifetime.

But coding-level is mor reliable and way mor fault-tolerant.

See the best answer of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes) for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For Detailed Explanation please go through this link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#96868

we can give via session parameters by giving the following command in php

```
<?php
       // Here we start as usual
       session_set_cookie_params('3600'); // 1 hour
       session_start();
?>
```

Hope it helps thank you